# Why do red muscle fibres have more mitochondria than white muscle fibre but less ATP than White muscle fibres?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles

This is a question given in my Anatomy book and I am really confused because logically the substance which have more mitochondria should have more ATP as mitochondria is the power house of cell.But the question contrast the logic.

Comment: It would be good to see some figures to support the assertion in the question. What is really needed is ATP/ADP ratios. I appreciate that you trust your book, but anatomy isn’t biochemistry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the difference in mitochondrial protein expression of red and white muscle fibres. There is difference in posttranslational modification, which leads to functional difference as red muscle contraction is slow, and white muscle contraction is rapid.

Metabolic control in mitochondria contributes in speed of activity and cellular energy production. So, these differences effect the cellular energy levels in both white and red muscle fibres.

Following factors also contribute to the ATP production:
White muscle mitochondria have higher proton leak. 
Red muscle contain high palmitic acid and oleic acid, but white muscle possess more phosphate ions.
Collagen and elastic fibers are largely distributed in red muscle mitochondria, whereas high titin levels and densely packed sarcomeres are present in white muscles. Whereas high levels of long sarcomeres are present in red muscles.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3118618/

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/bmri/2018/5816875/

Answer (score -1):

MacIntosh, Brian R.; Gardiner, Phillip F.; McComas, Alan J. (2006). Skeletal Muscle: Form and Function. Human Kinetics. ISBN 978-0-7360-4517-9.

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myocyte?wprov=sfla1 ][1]

[1]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myocyte?wprov=sfla1[image][image]

Good question,  I guess that high production could be linked to higher relative consume of ATP which could depend of necessity of energy and ATPase effectivity/ concentration of ATPase.

I suggest you to investigate the reference cited above.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. It discriminates against those sight impediments and need to use screen readers.